# Does UNION or UNION all build one massive query that locks all tables selected?

Tags: sql-server

I'm being told by my lead DBA that I wrote poorly formed code because I used a UNION ALL to accumulate results of successive queries on different tables.  I thought when a query with multiple select statements that had results UNIONed executed separately so when each select statement executes it places a shared lock on the table that is released when finished and the next select starts.
I thought the results were accumulated in some buffer or tmp table.

Would someone kindly tell me what goes on behind the scenes and what resources consumed when a results of a hundred select statements are UNIONed.  Each select operates on one table and collects schema, Table, and Column names.

Sorry, I don't have query plan.  The DBA complained the query was too big to show much of the plan.  His comments are below the query.

```
SELECT 'R_Stage' as TheSchema, 'DateFrozenSectionModF63x086' as TheTable, 'PersonModTextStaffSID' as TheColumn, COUNT(*) as NullCount 
FROM [R_Stage].[DateFrozenSectionModF63x086] WHERE [PersonModTextStaffSID] = -1  
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'R_Stage' as TheSchema, 'DateFrozenSectionModF63x086' as TheTable, 'LabDataLabSubjectSID' as TheColumn, COUNT(*) as NullCount 
FROM [R_Stage].[DateFrozenSectionModF63x086] WHERE [LabDataLabSubjectSID] = -1  
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'R_Stage' as TheSchema, 'DateFrozenSectionModF63x086' as TheTable, 'LabDataPatientSID' as TheColumn, COUNT(*) as NullCount 
FROM [R_Stage].[DateFrozenSectionModF63x086] WHERE [LabDataPatientSID] = -1  
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'R_Stage' as TheSchema, 'DateGrossDescChangedF63x087' as TheTable, 'PersonModTextStaffSID' as TheColumn, COUNT(*) as NullCount 
FROM [R_Stage].[DateGrossDescChangedF63x087] WHERE [PersonModTextStaffSID] = -1  
UNION 
ALL SELECT 'R_Stage' as TheSchema, 'DateGrossDescChangedF63x087' as TheTable, 'LabDataLabSubjectSID' as TheColumn, COUNT(*) as NullCount 
FROM [R_Stage].[DateGrossDescChangedF63x087] WHERE [LabDataLabSubjectSID] = -1  
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'R_Stage' as TheSchema, 'DateGrossDescChangedF63x087' as TheTable, 'LabDataPatientSID' as TheColumn, COUNT(*) as NullCount 
FROM [R_Stage].[DateGrossDescChangedF63x087] WHERE [LabDataPatientSID] = -1  
UNION ALL
```

In any case the query above could have certainly been written in a much more efficient way. As written for every table in the query it will scan the entire table for every UNION which is 791 times. Just looking at the first few lines of the query we can see these are just count’s from the same table which could have been done with a single scan of this table using a CASE expression for the count and you would have gotten all the counts in one pass per table. 
The bottom line is that right now we only have a few users on the FRE and processes like this are already affecting many  users / jobs. Imagine when we have hundreds to thousands of users. We simply can’t afford to run processes that are not vetted or properly tested like these two examples. This is nothing personal and should not be taken as such, it is all about the overall well being of the server and all the users. It is part of my job to point out such issues so they can be addressed when I see them and this is unquestionably one of those times. These can’t be run again until they are rewritten to ensure they do what they are intended to do and that they are efficient enough to not cause issues with other processes.

Comment: Please check you query plan for what goes on behind the scenes!!

Comment: There isn't enough information posted here to provide to a complete answer. At the very least you would need to post the actual execution plan.

Comment: This depends on what is being done in the union statements. Generaly, sqlserver will release locks as soon as possible. Ideally, each statement will lock, read and release, however, there is no way to be certain unless you post a sample. Are there JOINS, EXISTS or other built-in functions being used in the union statements? Many actions can cause sql to hold on to locks longer than expected. There are different lock types acquired with different effects. In a UNION all, I would bet the table-level locks will persist until the query has completed, however, these would normally not be Exclusive.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a query plan.  The DBA complained the query was so large he couldn't see much of it anyway and therefore wasn't useful.  It was a different DBA that said a UNION builds a huge query.  I'm just trying to make sense of what both are saying because I don't think SQL works this way.

There are no joins so each select is on 1 table.
There are no exists, no functions, no procedures.  I'm counting a single column in each select.  

Does this help?

Comment: If you want to see locking/unlocking you can trace the events Lock:Acquired and Lock:Released in Profiler.

Comment: Was afraid the profiler is where I would see locks.  I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 4):

The advice from your DBA seems quite reasonable. He/she doesn't mention locking, and it's not clear why you've mentioned that as the problem.

As the DBA states, you're executing 791 queries that the database engine then unions together. This will impose a load on the database. Assuming your DBA is correct about those queries being full table scans, that means the entire table is going to be read 791 times.

Regardless of any locking, that is going to thrash the disks, overrun file system and database caches, and load up the CPU running those queries.

Assuming your database is large enough that it doesn't fit in the RAM file system or database cache, that means it has to be read from disk in full each time. 
If the query were rewritten as your DBA advises so that it only made 1 full table scan through the database, the impact on the file system would be 1/791 of the query as currently written.

If your database does indeed take read locks at the same time, your query will impact updaters of that table 791 times.

Your DBA's recommendations have the effect of making the proposed query roughly 791 times as efficient.

If we assume just as a working example that your table is 100 meg, at a disk read speed of 100 mb/s it will take around 1 second to process each of 791 queries, so the full query would take around 14 minutes. Rewritten as your DBA advises it will take around 1 second.

This isn't a locking problem, it's a classic I/O performance problem. If you have locking problems as well, that just makes it worse.

The exact performance characteristics of your query depend on many factors, including how large the table is, what indexes are defined (noting that indexes can make a query slower in certain circumstances), how 'wide' the table is, the types of columns in the table, what hardware the query is running on, what database system you use, how fast the disks are, how much RAM your DB has, what else is happening on the system, and on and on. so it's not possible to give a definitive answer without a lot more information.

But avoiding 791 full table scans is a good start towards improved performance.

Comment: I'll add to this : you could have checked and/or solved this yourself. Your DBA gave you an actionable alternative to your query. You could/should have rewritten is as they suggested/required and run the two queries to test the performance differences. 

It would have only taken a few minutes to put together a trial of their suggestion, even if the proposed CASE wasn't 100% correct.

Then, if necessary, you could have had a discussion with your DBA based on facts and numbers rather than your assumptions.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  At least not directly.  I'll try and phrase it a different way.  Does SQL see this as a massive query of 700 tables that locks all 700 start to finish OR does SQL see this as 700 successive queries that locks one table at a time and release the lock when done that distinct query such that there is only one table lock at a time?

You do imply it's 700 successive yet separate queries with only one lock at a time.

Comment: I don't understand why you're focussing on locking.

Comment: It was alleged my process blocked multiple other processes accessing multiple tables but my process was blocked by yet another process.  I don't think it's possible for that to be true unless my process was massively parallel.  If that is the case the locks would last a few seconds.

BTW: I've revised my query FROM statement to include WITH (NOLOCK) so it won't be possible for my process to block anything.

Comment: 1) Even without locks your query is running way slower than it should and it will be trashing disks, which is slowing down other processes as a side effect. So you haven't stopped it from blocking other processes; you (may) have stopped the locks, but you're still blocking access to the disks
2) Your DBA gave you a perfectly valid way to greatly improve the performance, which would have reduced the disk impact, the CPU impact, the cache impact and also reduced the locking time even without NOLOCK
For the record, shared locks are released when data is read on the standard isolation level.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry that post just made my eyes hurt. It sounds like you are needing to write a script to clean up or identify a problem. To make this easy You could automate as script that will spit out smallish testable sql statements code before you post up those 300 tables. If your dba will let you use cursors and temp tables, both of which should be avoided when possible, however, this seems more like an identify the problem and or clean up issue rather than focus on efficiency. That being said, I would not want to lock those tables up on a production system for periods of time...so do a lot of smaller task to reduce locks and reach the same goal. You can run this script in sql server admin and copy the output as input to give to your dba, maybe it helps.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE  @OUTPUT TABLE
(  
    TheSchema NVARCHAR(45),
    TheTable NVARCHAR(45),
    Field1 NVARCHAR(45),
    Field2 NVARCHAR(45),
    Field3 NVARCHAR(45)
)

INSERT @OUTPUT SELECT 'R_Stage','DateFrozenSectionModF63x086','PersonModTextStaffSID','LabDataLabSubjectSID','LabDataPatientSID'
INSERT @OUTPUT SELECT 'R_Stage','DateFrozenSectionModF63x087','PersonModTextStaffSID','LabDataLabSubjectSID','LabDataPatientSID'
INSERT @OUTPUT SELECT 'R_Stage','DateFrozenSectionModF63x088','PersonModTextStaffSID','LabDataLabSubjectSID','LabDataPatientSID'
INSERT @OUTPUT SELECT 'R_Stage','DateFrozenSectionModF63x089','PersonModTextStaffSID','LabDataLabSubjectSID','LabDataPatientSID'
INSERT @OUTPUT SELECT 'R_Stage','DateFrozenSectionModF63x090','PersonModTextStaffSID','LabDataLabSubjectSID','LabDataPatientSID'
INSERT @OUTPUT SELECT 'R_Stage','DateFrozenSectionModF63x091','PersonModTextStaffSID','LabDataLabSubjectSID','LabDataPatientSID'
INSERT @OUTPUT SELECT 'R_Stage','DateFrozenSectionModF63x092','PersonModTextStaffSID','LabDataLabSubjectSID','LabDataPatientSID'
INSERT @OUTPUT SELECT 'R_Stage','DateFrozenSectionModF63x093','PersonModTextStaffSID','LabDataLabSubjectSID','LabDataPatientSID'
INSERT @OUTPUT SELECT 'R_Stage','DateFrozenSectionModF63x094','PersonModTextStaffSID','LabDataLabSubjectSID','LabDataPatientSID'
INSERT @OUTPUT SELECT 'R_Stage','DateFrozenSectionModF63x095','PersonModTextStaffSID','LabDataLabSubjectSID','LabDataPatientSID'



DECLARE @TheSchema NVARCHAR(45),@TheTable NVARCHAR(45),@Field1 NVARCHAR(45),@Field2 NVARCHAR(45),@Field3 NVARCHAR(45)

DECLARE LOOP CURSOR FOR
SELECT TheSchema,TheTable,Field1,Field2,Field3 FROM @OUTPUT


PRINT '

IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  WHERE  TABLE_NAME = ''__MY_SCAN''))
DROP TABLE __MY_SCAN


CREATE TABLE  __MY_SCAN(
    TheShema NVARCHAR(45),
    TheTable NVARCHAR(45),
    Field1NullCount INT,
    Field2NullCount INT,
    Field3NullCount INT
)'

OPEN LOOP 
FETCH NEXT FROM LOOP INTO @TheSchema,@TheTable,@Field1,@Field2,@Field3
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS=0) BEGIN
    PRINT 
        'INSERT __MY_SCAN
            SELECT 
                '''+@TheSchema+''' AS '+@TheSchema+',
                '''+@TheTable+''' AS '+@TheTable+',
                COUNT(Field1),
                COUNT(Field2),
                COUNT(Field3)
            FROM
            (   
                SELECT       
                    Field1=CASE WHEN '+@Field1+'=-1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
                    Field2=CASE WHEN '+@Field2+'=-1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
                    Field3=CASE WHEN '+@Field3+'=-1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                FROM
                    '+@TheTable+'
                WHERE
                    '+@Field1+'=-1 OR '+@Field2+'=-1 OR '+@Field3+'=-1
            )AS X
            GO'

    FETCH NEXT FROM LOOP INTO @TheSchema,@TheTable,@Field1,@Field2,@Field3
END
CLOSE LOOP
DEALLOCATE LOOP

PRINT '
SELECT * FROM __MY_SCAN 
GO
DROP TABLE __MY_SCAN
GO
'
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  A problem has been identified and I'm searching for everywhere it exists.

Yes, this query is built with cursor and you're seeing the @sql variable that is executed at the end.  I did add with (NOLOCK) to my FROM statement.  It runs in 4 minutes and counts columns it found ending with characters 'SID'.  Some of these tables have billions of rows so I'm satisfied with performance.

My question is how many table locks are there given each select only operates on one table.  Is it just one at a time or are all 700 locked at beginning and released at end?

Comment: That is not an easy question to answer. There are multiple lock types some exclusive some only signal an intent to lock. There is a pecking order of locks can be placed on tables,pages and or rows. Locking can get complex and pain to debug. There are tools that let you analays the locks and resources your query consumes, I would look there. If you use NOLOCK then that reduces the likelihood of a deadlockbut but will add little gain to performance. The statement above will only scan each table once, like your dba suggests. In the end, I would listen to your dba.